# How to solve equation to the third power

Tags: polynomials

I have the information that:
$$
x^3 − x^2 −1 =0
$$
Has a "positive real root" of: $x \approx 1.4655\ldots$

My questions are, please:

1) What is a "positive real root".

2) How one gets from the formula to $1.4655$?

3) What is the technique used to solve this in similar problems?

Comment: you can use the cubic formula see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html

Comment: 1) A solution to the equation that is a real, positive number. 2) It's complicated. The true answer is $$\frac13\left(1 + \sqrt[3]{\frac{29-3\sqrt{93}}{2}} +  \sqrt[3]{\frac{29+3\sqrt{93}}{2}}\right)$$ 3) It's [complicated](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/).

Comment: Actually solving the cubic equation isn't as complicated as writing down the cubic formula and then inserting the numbers. The issue here is quite similar to solving, say 4  linear equations with 4 unknowns. Given some set of equations with specified integers as coefficients, you just use Gaussian elimination. But what you don't want to do is solve this set symbolically in case of undetermined coefficients and then use that solution as the general solution in which you should substitute the numbers for the coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A positive real root is the point say  $x=a$ ($\forall \ \ a>0$) where the curve intersects the x-axis.

In general, to find one real root of the polynomial equation $$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\ldots +a_1x+a_0=0$$

Apply Newton Raphson's iteration formula given 
as follows $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Where, $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\ldots +a_1x+a_0$

$x=x_0$ is the initial expected real root.

Now, we  $f(x)=x^3-x^2-1$ $\implies f(x)=3x^2-2x$

Let, initial expected root $x_0=1$ then we have

Iteration-1: $$f(1)=1^3-1^2-1=-1$$$$ f'(1)=3(1^2)-2(1)=1$$

$$x_1=x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}=1-\frac{f(1)}{f'(1)}=1-\frac{(-1)}{1}=2$$

Iteration-2: $$f(2)=2^3-2^2-1=3$$$$ f'(2)=3(2^2)-2(2)=8$$

$$x_2=x_1-\frac{f(x_1)}{f'(x_1)}=2-\frac{f(2)}{f'(2)}=2-\frac{3}{8}=1.625$$

Iteration-3: $$f(1.625)=(1.625)^3-(1.625)^2-1=0.650391$$$$ f'(1.625)=3(1.625^2)-2(1.625)=4.671875$$

$$x_3=x_2-\frac{f(x_2)}{f'(x_2)}=1.625-\frac{f(1.625)}{f'(1.625)}=1.625-\frac{0.650391}{4.671875}\approx 1.485786$$

Iteration-4: $$f(1.485786)=(1.485786)^3-(1.485786)^2-1=0.072402$$$$ f'(1.485786)=3(1.485786^2)-2(1.485786)=3.651108$$

$$x_4=x_3-\frac{f(x_3)}{f'(x_3)}=1.485786-\frac{f(1.485786)}{f'(1.485786)}=1.485786-\frac{0.072402}{3.651108}\approx 1.465956 $$

Iteration-5:

$$f(1.465956)=(1.465956)^3-(1.465956)^2-1=0.001352$$ $$f'(1.465956)=3(1.465956^2)-2(1.465956)=3.515169$$

$$ x_5=x_4-\frac{f(x_4)}{f'(x_4)}=1.465956-\frac{f(1.465956)}{f'(1.465956)}=1.465956-\frac{0.001352}{3.515169}\approx 1.465571 $$

Above root can be approximated as $x\approx 1.4655$

Comment: Just add a numerical calculation WoframAlpha:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=newton%27s+method+x%5E3+%E2%88%92+x%5E2+%E2%88%921%2C+x0%3D5

Answer (score 2):

As $x>0$ it is a positive root.

There is no really nice way to get to that solution, one possibilty is to use [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method) which gives you a formula for these equations: $$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0.$$ If you don't need the exact solution I'd suggest something like [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).